# Connect to SMB server on startup

Tags: macbook-pro, smb, webserver

I got a late 2017 macbook pro running the High Sierra update. I am wondering if its possible to **auto connect** to a **smb** server. I need to do this manually everytime i start up at work. And as small as it is. It gets quite annoying!

I have found a way to connect to AFP servers using a script (but im not using any) but that didnt work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a number of options for doing this, but the easiest way is to just use your Login Items. More specifically:

1. In the Finder, press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (or click on the Go menu and select Connect to Server...)
2. Now enter the server address
3. Click on the <kbd>Connect</kbd> button
4. IMPORTANT: If you're a *registered user*, when entering your login details you **must** ensure you enable the option for remembering your password in keychain
5. Once connected, go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
6. Select the Login Items tab
7. Now navigate to the mounted server (e.g. on your desktop) and drag it to the Login Items list
8. OPTIONAL: If you don't want the server window to open every time you startup, you can click on the Hide checkbox on the left of the server in the Login Items list

**NOTES:**

- At step 4 the reason I say you must opt to remember the password is that macOS needs to remember this in order to be able to log in automatically!
- At step 7, if you don't see the server mounted on your desktop, then go to Finder > Preferences > General and tick the checkbox for Connected servers.
- Keep in mind that if for whatever reason your Mac can't connect to the server, this may in fact become more annoying then having to connect manually.

**If your server doesn't mount on the desktop**

If you can't get the server to mount on your desktop, try following these steps instead:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. Select the Login Items tab
3. Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button at the bottom of the Login Items list
4. In the window that opens, click on the server in your left Sidebar (or navigate to it)
5. If you're not already connected to it, then connect to it through this window. (IMPORTANT: If you're a *registered user*, when entering your login details you **must** ensure you enable the option for remembering your password in keychain)
6. Once connected, navigate to and select whichever folder on your server you use the most
7. After a moment the <kbd>add</kbd> button will become active. Click on this
8. Now the folder you selected at Step 6 will be added to your Login Items
9. OPTIONAL: If you don't want the server window to open every time you startup, you can click on the Hide checkbox on the left of the server in the Login Items list

To show network mounted volumes (SMB, AFP, NFS, etc.) on your desktop, issue the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple. finder ShowMountedServersOnDesktop —bool true
```

Comment: The server does not create a desktop icon of the server. It only appears in the sidebar in Finder.

Comment: Ah, okay, I've just added an extra note re Step 7.

Comment: I already had it checked, still no server on the desktop.

Comment: Any way i can do it without having it on the desktop?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed your comment. When I get a chance I'll come back and revisit this for you, although it may not be until tomorrow sometime.

Comment: defaults write com.apple. finder ShowountedServersOnDesktop —bool true doesnt work. It falls on --boot and true

Comment: I got the servers to show on my desktop. Its under finder -> preferences -> General and then show connected servers

Comment: Ah, just realised there was a typo in Allan's edit - the command should be okay now. Glad you got your server mounted, although that's what the 2nd bullet point was about. More importantly, have you been able to get it to auto connect upon login?

Comment: No i have not. I have to use a VPN to be able to connect to the server. The VPN does not start up in time so the server cant make a connection :/

Comment: Whoa! That's an important piece of detail not included in your question! :( The steps in my answer **are** how you connect to an SMB server upon login, so at this point I'm not sure if you'd be better to edit this question to reflect the VPN requirement, or whether it'd be better to accept this answer and then ask another question about automatically connecting to a VPN on startup?

Comment: Upon reflection it's probably more useful for others if you accept this answer and ask another, as they both stand on their own merits. In the meantime, I can start getting an answer ready for you re the VPN question. Connecting to a VPN on startup requires using a script, and I've got one I use when I'm working remotely with a MBP, so it shouldn't take too long to get an answer ready for you. Basically you’ll need to action both answers to achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: The VPN is already starting up on startup and also connects to it. Im using Tunnelblick for that. But it does not connect fast enough to allow the server to connect.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, I would think we can get around that. Maybe use a login script instead to handle the connection to the SMB server, but script it so that it waits *x* minutes before connecting. Or, unless you actually have to use Tunnelblick, we use macOS to handle the VPN connection and then use the login script I use to first connect to the VPN and then to the server, all in the one script. If you **do** have to use Tunnelblick, then I could check to see if that's scriptable. A few things to think about here. How long does it typically take for the VPN connection to be established?

Comment: I have to use Tunnelblick. Because for some reason it wont allow me to connect otherwise.

Comment: This does not work for me. I suspect it's because I don't have to login for the SMB share because my Mac login is somehow coming from Active Directory.

Comment: This has always worked well for me, but: The "Hide" checkbox does nothing for me, and never did. Always get one Finder window per server on startup, which is a bit annoying. Don't know if anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different solution that allows me to automate the process even further.

Here is the code I use:

```
tell application "Viscosity"
    set connectionState to "dunno"
    repeat until (connectionState = "Connected")
        if connectionState = "Disconnected" then
            connect "VPN_CONNECTION1"
            connect "VPN_CONNECTION2"
        end if
        set connectionState to state of connections where name is equal to "VPN_CONNECTION1"
        set connectionState to connectionState as string
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        if (count of windows) is 0 then
            mount volume "smb://username:password@IP_address/share"
            mount volume "smb://username:password@IP_address/share"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

The above apple script will automatically startup my Viscosity VPN and upon a succesfull connection it will start to connect to my SMB servers. If you export the code to an application and then put it into your login items it will automatically connect everytime you startup.

Hope this helps anyone.

Kind regards,
Granny